# How to access to mongoose models from a hook

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose, feathersjs

I'm trying to get direct access to the models that were created with the feathers CLI. In the feathers-mongoose documentation it's stated that:

Note: You can get access to the Mongoose model via this.Model inside a hook and use it as usual. See the Mongoose Guide for more information on defining your model.

I've tried to access the model from a custom hook like this:

```
module.exports = function (options = {}) {
  return async context => {
    this.Model
    return context
  }
}
```

I was expecting the model back but I just get `undefined`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First is try not to use arrow functions.

```
return async function(context) => {
    ...
}
```

I suggest accessing it via context `context.service('serviceName').Model'`

Comment: Changing the arrow function worked. I opted to access as you said via the service like this `context.app.service('service').Model`. Thank you :)